# integrate netbeans, symfony and dart

Tags: javascript, symfony, twig, dart

is there any nice method for using Dart language instead of js in Symfony 2 project?
I am looking for similar solution to less-css compiler for twig

Comment: you need to write a dart plugin for assetic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a dart filter for assetic: https://github.com/kriswallsmith/assetic/tree/master/src/Assetic/Filter

You should be able to use it with the AsseticBundle for symfony2. There is not much information on the most filters, so you gonna have to dig in a bit into the whole assetic/AsseticBundle functionality, but it's not that complicated.

Afterwards you should be able to use dart the same way you use less.